# a broken PNG output in mapserver

Tags: mapserver, png, mapfile

i want to show my shapefile on the web 
my template file is:

```
<html>
<head><title>Simple Mapserver Template HTML Document</title></head>
<body>
<img src="[img]" border=0 width=300 height=400>
</body>
</html>
```

my map code is:

```
MAP
NAME "parcels_map"
STATUS ON
SIZE 400 300
EXTENT 489885 5450946 490904 5451637
UNITS METERS
SHAPEPATH "shpfile"
IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255

WEB
TEMPLATE "template.html"
IMAGEPATH "C:\\wamp64\\www\\parcel\\output\\"
IMAGEURL "/output/"
END


LAYER
NAME "parcel_boundaries"
DATA parcels
STATUS DEFAULT
TYPE LINE
CLASS
NAME "parcels_color"
COLOR 255 215 0
END
END

# end of map file
END
```

i send a request to mapserv.exe in CGI mode and then my output is a broken PNG in my browser while a png file create in my output folder.
what should i do to solve my problem 
please help me.I'm a beginner to mapserver and totally have disappointed

Comment: if you open the "broken" png in a text editor what do you see?

Comment: when i click on the image and open it in new tab in my browser an error accur :The requested URL /output/parcels_map151064593568.png was not found on this server....Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80